# Does one shake hands with 6 men/11 women per year who have recently masturbated and not washed their hands?

Tags: sexuality, masturbation

I've received this email before, and tracked down [a requote online](https://able2know.org/topic/119791-1):

> Annually you will shake hands with 11 women who have recently masturbated and failed to wash their hands.
>
> Annually you will shake hands with 6 men who have recently masturbated and failed to wash their hands.

I'm wondering if there's any evidence to support this. At the very least, I'm surprised by the ratio, given the fact that men [seem to masturbate with higher frequency than women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation#Frequency.2C_age.2C_and_sex):

> Similar results have been found in a 2007 British national probability survey. It was found that, between individuals aged 16 to 44, 95% of men and 71% of women masturbated at some point in their lives. 73% of men and 37% of women reported masturbating in the four weeks before their interview, while 53% of men and 18% of women reported masturbating in the previous seven days. ([Cited source in Wikipedia](https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs10508-006-9123-6))

Comment: The domain of the unreferenced statistic is so large and vague, it seems meaningless. Consider the difference between a politician and someone who works from home. The number of handshakes they make annually probably varies by three orders of magnitude. Calculating averages in such circumstances is largely meaningless - the precision given seems out of whack with the variance. And that's assuming it is an an accurate average, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Another claim (or one very similar) in that link has already been [addressed and debunked here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1908/4020).

Comment: I suspect one big reason the numbers could be "out of whack" may be clearer with a little perspective that's rooted in social taboos:  _Do people wash their hands after picking their noses?  Do many people truthfully admit to doing that?  On a similar "vein," I wonder if many people truthfully admit to masturbating._

Comment: Why should I care? If this is proven to be true, how is it dangerous for me?

Comment: @Suma: is that really your criteria for good questions? looking to the right, how will you act different depending on effectiveness of Nielsen TV ratings, if Cathy the Great died from horse injuries, or how many languages people have created? I probably won't act differently either; I was just curious if the claim had any substantiation whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think this question is ever answerable with empirical evidence :p

Comment: @Suma it's theoretically possible that this could be one of the many [ways in which the HPV virus is transmitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus#Hands) (it can survive on and pass on from skin for limited amounts of time) although it would be rare. Most transmission is sexual, but virgins do sometimes (rarely) get infected, and this is a possible method.